# Не сохраняется состояние .addToBackStack

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Код фрагмента

```
public class DropboxFragment extends Fragment {
String dir="/";
ListView listView;
public DropboxFragment(String dir) {
    this.dir=dir;
}

void showFiles(){
    ListFiles listFiles=new ListFiles(AppConstant.getDBSession(),dir,handler);
    listFiles.execute();
}

private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        ArrayList<FileObject> result = msg.getData().getParcelableArrayList("data");
        final FileObjectAdapter adapter = new FileObjectAdapter(getContext(), result);

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (adapter.getFile(position).isDir()) {
                    dir = dir + adapter.getFile(position).getName() + "/";
                    showFragment(dir);

                }
            }
        });

    }
};

void showFragment(String dir){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager=getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container,new DropboxFragment(dir));
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    showFiles();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.dropbox_fragment, container, false);
    listView= (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewDropbox);
    return view;
}
```

}

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вхожу в папку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возвращаюсь назад

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мало информации. Наверное, дело в реализации фрагмента.

Comment: Поправил ,посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: У вас что-то очень странное в коде. Хандлер вам не нужен для получения результата из таска. Для этого OnPostExecute есть. Стартовать загрузку лучше из OnCreateView. Плюс, попробуйте сохранять полученные данные в OnSaveInstanceState и восстанавливать потом.